# Libraries for building projects? Can I compile C++ using C++, or java with python, or java with C++, etc?

Tags: java, c++, frameworks, build, compilation

Are there any libraries or frameworks out there that are designed to facilitate the building of projects from within another full fledged programming language?

It is very easy to specify logic, sets, and complicated rules in programming languages like C++, java, etc, but it seems like an uphill battle to do these things in a Makefile. I haven't dug into Ant or Maven or any of the other building tools yet, but if I could just write all my build logic into a C++ program it would be much easier! (Assuming I had some helpful tools.)

Comment: I know someone who uses maven to do this (and the maven page says it can be used for non-java builds), but haven't done it myself. I did a lot of non-ruby tasks in rake, but that's just because ruby is a good system scripting language, not because such tasks were well supported by rake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you'd like to look at this project: http://www.scons.org/

But, what would you like to do besides specifying modules dependencies and build rules? I think putting too much logic into the build system is just creating another extra problem; try to stick to well known configuration tools and you'll have one thing less to worry about.

About Maven and Ant, they are a little bit java-centric, but can be used for any kind of projects and have loads of plugins to perform almost any task you could imagine. If you prefer to use a more unix-oriented environment, but want a higher level layer on top `make` you can use the [Autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Comment: I will definitely learn some more build tools, but I thought, if we use these other languages to do all of the real work, why don't we use them (directly) to do the build logic. I would simply like not to be forced to wrestle logic into the form of individual build rules and dependency relationships if they are poorly suited to them. In the event something felt cludgy, I could easily do it a different way. I suppose I was looking for tools to abstract the compiling process, help build dependency trees, abstract file system access, etc.

Comment: We (usually) don't want to use them *directly* because they are overkill. Rephrasing Peter Parker's uncle: "With a great power comes a great complexity". Domain Specific Languages are there to make our lives easier. Anyway, SCons is what you want, a build system programmable in Python.

Comment: this link: http://www.electric-cloud.com/blog/2010/08/11/the-last-word-on-scons-performance/ doesn't make scons look that great for big projects. Not that the project I'm working on is huge right now, but it looks like I need to learn more than one tool. (I guess I could try to code my own silver bullet as a hobby project!) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Dig into Ant and/or Maven. These can handle all the different tasks needed for creating complicated builds. This will save you reinventing the wheel by trying to replicate all those features in C++. I think the issue you are struggling with is that you need to spend the time to learn to use a new build tool.